# Find Two numbers in an array such that their sum equals the number given by user

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I know this question has been asked a large number of times in the community. Even after using c# library functions my code doesn't work and shows no Such pairs exist for all indexes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
namespace test
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i, nts, index1,index2;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int[] numbers = new int[10];
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            numbers[i] = rnd.Next(200, 984);
        Array.Sort(numbers);
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(numbers[i] + " ");

        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the sum to search\n");
        nts = Console.Read();
        for(index1=0;index1<numbers.Length;index1++)
        {
            index2 = Array.BinarySearch(numbers,(nts - numbers[index1]));
            if (index2 < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No such pairs for " + index1);
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Numbers found" + numbers[index1] + "and" + numbers[index2]);
                break;
            }

        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure the sum you look for can be found in the array? Your array is pretty small (10 numbers) and your range is quite large (between 200 and 984). Have you tested with a smaller range (e.g. between 1 and 10)?

Comment: Yes i did.but the problem stays.

Comment: `rnd.Next(200, 984);` is not very good test data... Consider starting with test method that will pass hard-coded array with known numbers and known "sum" to know what results to expect. Random numbers provide random results (unless you get usage of `Random` wrong, which is not your case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your algorithm to solve the problem is fine, the issue is in reading the number. So you are actually finding the wrong values.

```
Console.Read()
```

Reads the next character from the standard input stream. (ASCII value 's in ntp)

```
nts = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: And that saved the day!my bad.